# How to use css fill: on image elements inside svg?

Tags: svg

```css
.i image,
.i path,
.i {
  fill: red;
  stroke: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="i">
    <image class="i" xlink:href="https://nextgenthemes.com/wp-content/bubble.svg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</svg>
```

It does work if I use the `<use>` element and reference a symbol from a svg definitions file.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wecutonepe/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Try using the "stroke" attribute instead of "fill"

Comment: Also maybe try doing it inline, there might be an issue with your stylesheet being referenced

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes

Comment: Its works fine with fill when its a svg with a reference to a svg sprite with the use tag. Thanks for your suggestions but this do no help. Looks like its not possible. And I was about this think I found THE HTTP/2 read solution for icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG `<image>` element does not accept `fill` as an attribute. So it would not accept the CSS `fill` equivalent.

W3C SVG `<image>` element: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#ImageElement

**Attribute definitions for the SVG `<image>` element :**

- **x** = The x-axis coordinate of one corner of the rectangular region into which the referenced document is placed.
  If the attribute is not specified, the effect is as if a value of '0' were specified.
  Animatable: yes.
- **y** = The y-axis coordinate of one corner of the rectangular region into which the referenced document is placed.
  If the attribute is not specified, the effect is as if a value of '0' were specified.
  Animatable: yes.
- **width** = The width of the rectangular region into which the referenced document is placed.
  A negative value is an error (see Error processing). A value of zero disables rendering of the element.
  Animatable: yes.
- **height** = The height of the rectangular region into which the referenced document is placed.
  A negative value is an error (see Error processing). A value of zero disables rendering of the element.
  Animatable: yes.
- **xlink:href** = A IRI reference.
  Animatable: yes.

If it works with the SVG `<use>` element than use it!

Comment: I feared this. The reason I don't want to use `<use>` is I would need to include svg-for-everybody because not all browsers support referecing to external svg definitions with anchors `svgdev.svg#icon1`. Also I am coding this for a HTTP/2 world where sprites are actually bad practice. So I would actually reference a single icons with a ID in lots of definition files. The use without a ID to a simple svg file did not work with use `<use>` my guess is that it is not supported/intended to do that. So when I came across `<image>` I was happy and thought this is the solution I need.

Comment: I use `<img>` now and then a small JS function to transform it to a inline `<svg>` to then be able to fill the `path` interestingly I not needed `path` in the CSS before.

Comment: When using the `<use>` element and if it is referencing SVG elements inside a SVG `<defs>` element with CSS. You can not use CSS on anything inside a `<defs>` element due to CSS not being directly rendered in `<defs>` or <symbol> elements. In that case you must change the attributes instead. `<defs>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs .. But glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible, for two different reasons.

1. SVGs loaded via HTML `<img>` or `background-image`, or via an SVG `<image>` can be considered as being rendered to a static form whose contents are not styleable by the parent.  Think of it as having been converted to a bitmap.
2. CSS rules do not apply across document boundaries.  You cannot have rules in one document (the HTML) that style elements in another document (in this case the SVG `bubble.svg`).